# Master detail in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, master-detail

I try to write a small app that get a list from REST API and displays details for each selected item. I was looking for a simple tutorial on how to transfer the selected id from the list view to the detail view, but couldn't figure out. I assume I need to use the Master-detail technique.

Here's the code:

The list view:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="gadgetDetails in gadgettDetails">

        <div>
                <a href="#/gadgets/{{gadgetDetails.id}}"><p>{{gadgetDetails.type}}</p></a>
                <p>{{gadgetDetails.manufacturer}}</p>
        </div>  
        <hr />
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the detail view

```
<div>
     <p><a href="#/gadgetLists">Go back to Gadgets list</a></p>

      <p>{{gadgetDetails[2].type}}</p>
      <p>{{gadgetDetails[2].color}}</p>
      <p>{{gadgetDetails[2].manufcturer}}</p>
</div>
```

So just for the question I've put 2 (the second object in the JSON list that I get from the REST API , but it actually should be `gadgetDetails[i].type`
but I couldn't figure out how to get the index (for example i) for each item in the list

This the controller:

```
GadgetListCtrl.controller('gdgtList', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
$http.get('https:.../gadgets.json').
    then(function(response) {
        $scope.gadgettDetails = response.data;
    });

});
```

So the question is how to display for each item its details by the id.
Thanks

Comment: what is your routing settings in `.config` block? it depends on that too

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this by [angular ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) params

below is dummy code

in **.config** block

```
$stateProvider
    .state('gadgets', {
        url: "/gadgets/:id",
        templateUrl: 'gadgetDetail.html',
        controller: 'gadgetController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        params: {
         id: null
        }
    });
```

and in controller file, you can access the id  as below

```
  .controller('GadgetController', function($state, $stateParams) {

    var selectedID = $state.params.id;
    //alternatively you can get using $stateParams service
    // $stateParams.id 

  if(selectedID) {
   // get detail of gadget
  }
});
```